# Insert Record into two tables with one to many relation by using linq to ado.net entity froamwork

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have above two tables and in department table `PersonID` is Foreign key of `PersonalInfo` table. I have web form which contains FirstName,SecondName,MobileNo and Department text boxes. So I am having problem to insert `PersonID` into `Department`.

Can you please let me know how can I store ID of `PersonalInfo` into `PersonID` of department by using linq to entityframework?

This is my code:

```
PersonalInfo myRecipient = new PersonalInfo();
myRecipient.FirstName = id_firstName.ToString();
myRecipient.SecondName = id_lastName.Text.ToString();
myRecipient.MobileNo = id_mobileNo.Text.ToString();
Department myDepartment = new Department();
myDepartment.Department1 = id_departmentName.Text.ToString();
MyEntity myDB = new MyEntity();

myDB.AddToPersonalInfoes(myRecipient);

myDB.AddToDepartments(myDepartment);
myDB.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EntityFramework you are working with **entities** and **references**. So you don't have to care about IDs. All you have to do is to *set a reference from Department to PersonalInfo*. EF will take care about your IDs, PKs and FKs!

```
try 
{
  // create objects, set properties ...
  PersonalInfo myRecipient = new PersonalInfo();
  myRecipient.FirstName = id_firstName.ToString(); // CHECK if value is valid (correct max length, ..)
  // and so on ..

  // set reference from Entity Department to Recipient
  myDepartment.PersonalInfo = myRecipient;

  myDB.AddToPersonalInfoes(myRecipient);
  myDB.AddToDepartments(myDepartment);
  myDB.SaveChanges();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  if (ex.InnerException!=null)
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
}
```

You may have a look at this [***blog***](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/05/entity-framework-inserting-objects-with.html), which illustrates this very nice!

Comment: I added the resference and got exception update exception was unhandle by user code.

Comment: base {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."} System.Exception {System.Data.UpdateException}

Comment: sorry what i need to inspect and how. pop up help to go at this link    http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHSQL%29&rd=true

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: editet answer - to show exception messages in output window while in debug mode

Comment: did you solve your problem? you marked an answer as best solution? if not, you should check all your text assignments (firstname, lastname, mobildno...) if they contain valid values!

Comment: Here are the two exception messages ex is "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." Inner is "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Thanks it works... it was an error in getting value in from text box

Answer (score 0):

```
myDepartment.PersonalInfo = myRecipient;
```

By the way, change the column name `Department` in the `Department` table to `DepartmentName`, so you won't get a property named `Department1`

Answer (score 0):

And you only need one of following code after the two new entities are associated as Amiram Korach specified:

```
    myDB.AddToPersonalInfoes(myRecipient);

    myDB.AddToDepartments(myDepartment);
```